# Multipart binary file POST in python 2.4

Tags: python, binary, multipart, python-2.4

I already checked a lot of code snippets but i could not get how to post multipart both text and binary files in single request with only python 2.4? [Here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/146306/) in comments mentioned something about BytesIO class but is not present in 2.4. (plain python, no third-party libraries) Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked at [poster](http://atlee.ca/software/poster/)?

Comment: If there is no way to do this without third-party, i will try to dig into poster sources. But i hope there is some kind of workaround.

Answer (score 0):

with Python 2.6 you can use requests library, here is snippet extracted from the [documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file):

```
>>> url = 'http://httpbin.org/post'
>>> files = {'report.xls': open('report.xls', 'rb')}

>>> r = requests.post(url, files=files)
>>> r.text
{
  "origin": "179.13.100.4",
  "files": {
    "report.xls": "<censored...binary...data>"
  },
  "form": {},
  "url": "http://httpbin.org/post",
  "args": {},
  "headers": {
    "Content-Length": "3196",
    "Accept-Encoding": "identity, deflate, compress, gzip",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "User-Agent": "python-requests/0.8.0",
    "Host": "httpbin.org:80",
    "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=127.0.0.1.502.21746.1321131593.786.1"
  },
  "data": ""
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if any version of requests supports Python 2.4.